# Проблема с сессиями PHP

Tags: php, сессия

Стандартная форма входа: логин, пароль, чекбокс на автовход через куки и кнопка submit. Если ввожу данные и отмечаю автовход, то происходит вторая ситуация (и если потом обновить страницу, то тоже "куки открыты, сессии закрыты", хотя они вроде как открыты).
Если же не кликаю на чекбокс, то происходит просто перезагрузка страницы и опять форма входа. Проверил: сессия на сервере и в куки пишется, то бишь проблема в другом. Попеременно комментил код и выяснил, что проблема в **isset($_REQUEST[session_name()])**. Он считает её пустой, даже если она есть.
Кто что может подсказать по этому поводу? Может есть вообще альтернативный способ проверки сессий и куки на существование?

```
//куки открыты, сессии открыты
if(!empty($_COOKIE['uk']) && isset($_REQUEST[session_name()]))
{
    session_start();
    echo "куки открыты, сессии открыты<br>";
}
//куки открыты, сессии закрыты
elseif(!empty($_COOKIE['uk']) && !isset($_REQUEST[session_name()]))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uk'] = $_COOKIE['uk'];
    echo "куки открыты, сессии закрыты<br>";
}
//куки закрыты, сессии открыты
elseif(empty($_COOKIE['uk']) && isset($_REQUEST[session_name()]))
{
    session_start();
    echo "куки закрыты, сессии открыты<br>";
}
//куки закрыты, сессии закрыты
else echo "куки закрыты, сессии закрыты<br>";


echo '|'.$_SESSION['id'].'|';
```

Comment: Самая частая проблема с сессиями это файл не в кодировке без BOM  А эта директива регулирует всего лишь порядок в массиве http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php Учтите, что файлы php.ini, поставляемые с дистрибутивом, по соображениям безопасности не содержат значение 'C' (cookies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле **.htaccess** добавил строку `php_value request_order "GPC"`, заработало

Comment: Через 2 дня не забудьте отметить свой ответ "галочкой", чтобы не висел в списке не отвеченных.

Comment: Почему кто-то минусонул его ответ? По правилам SO минусовать стоит неверные, либо "плохие" (т.е. такие, которые хоть и ведут к решению проблемы, но являются ужасным способом решения) ответы.

Comment: request_order string
Эта директива регулирует порядок, в котором PHP добавляет переменные GET, POST и Cookie в массив _REQUEST. Добавление производится слева направо, новые значения перезаписывают старые.